# Neovim: behavior different from vim with the same vimrc

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, neovim

I'm using Vim and now I'm moving to NeoVim. I have configured my `.vimrc` so that the hotkey `Control H/J/K/L` moves between panels. (seamlessly between vim and tmux also).

But now when I'm moving to NeoVim, I see that `Control H` doesn't switch to left panel, but moves the cursor one character left. This makes me confused. I think the behavior of Neovim and vim should be the same with the same `vimrc`.

Comment: Could you post your `.vimrc`, or at least the relevant parts from it?

Comment: wow. this is a well-know issue in nvim as describe here. https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator#it-doesnt-work-in-neovim-specifically-c-h

Comment: Post it as an answer. IMHO neovim questions *do* belong to this site, as long as they are clearly marked as such (as this post is).

Comment: Did you try: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#my-ctrl-h-mapping-doesnt-work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug from `nvim` and has officially discuss here:

[nvim bug when pressing Control+H](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator#it-doesnt-work-in-neovim-specifically-c-h)

Basically, that means you press Control+H, nvim will understand a backspace. So we must convert backspace again to open `TmuxNavigateLeft`

```
 <silent> <BS> :TmuxNavigateLeft<cr>
```